# Reading a image file in Jva

Tags: java, image, io

How to read a image in Java and convert it to *buffered* image?

Answer (score 7):

You need the Java 2D API for this. Here's a [Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html) about the subject. In the ["Working with Images"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) chapter you can learn how to [read/load](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) an image. Here's an extract of the tutorial:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: my answer... but please add at least a `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block.

Comment: Tell that the Sun guys ;) It was an 1:1 copypaste. But indeed certainly you need to handle the exception somehow instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

See [ImageIO.read()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File)).